# Keycloak Enable Maintenance Mode

Tags: keycloak

How do I enable maintenance mode in KC, which means redirecting customer dashboards to a single page, in this case the user accounts dashboard will redirect to maintenance page?

so for example

[image: accouts]

and the other Keycloack customer dashboards will be redirect to something like

[image]

this my be done manually by toggle some option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar request and found a way to make it "sort of maintainable" for us. 
But in my case, I had an NGINX reverse proxy running in front of keycloak.

1. To do Maintenance, we "disable" the Realm in Keycloak
   [image: Keycloak Disable Realm Setting]
2. Any request to the disabled realm returns **HTTP Status 400**, so we react on this in the NGINX reverse proxy config and return our "Maintenance Page"

```bash
proxy_intercept_errors on;

error_page 400 /maintenance.html;

location = /maintenance.html {
 internal;
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

In my case, we host the "Maintenance Page" directly on the NGINX host.
But you could aswell return a temporary redirect like

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;

error_page 400 @maintenance;

location @maintenance {
  return 302 https://yoursite.com/maintenance
}
```

But this is not a perfect solution.

Ideally, I want my "Testaccounts-Audience" still be able to log in.
So that we can verify the new config works as expected. And all other users e.g. "Productionaccounts-Audience" to receive a "Maintenance Page".

If someone can propose a good solution for this - keeping the realm "enabled" only for a test-audience, but redirect all other users, I'd appreciate it.

Regards,
Erich